# Can't register a service worker in chrome but in Firefox it is working

Tags: javascript, service-worker

Having a problem in registering a service worker in chrome is say in console log is Service worker registration failed: DOMException.
I used https on my site. and its running in livesite.
please see my code.

**main.js**

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  // Register a service worker hosted at the root of the
  // site using the default scope.
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js').then(function(registration) {
    console.log('Service worker registration succeeded:', registration);
  }, /*catch*/ function(error) {
    console.log('Service worker registration failed:', error);
  });
} else {
  console.log('Service workers are not supported.');
}
```

**sw.js** is empty Im trying to register my worker first before I add a code in this file.

**Console log in mozilla**
ServiceWorker registration successful with scope:  https://m.domain.com/ main.js:5:7

**Console log in chrome**
Service worker registration failed: DOMException.

Comment: check with your cookie setting ..   for similar error in firefox is resolve by cookie setting.
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49539306/firefox-service-worker-securityerror-domexception-the-operation-is-insecure

Comment: How are you creating the worker process? What is `navigator`?

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn that is a ServiceWorker and you do generally register it through the `window.navigator.serviceWorker` API. The question's title was wrong.

Comment: Okay... I thought that this was a Web Worker...

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a clearer error message somewhere? That sounds like something in the worker's code failed. Try to remove things until it doesn't throw anymore. And anyway, we'll need to see an [MCVE] to be able to help you.