# cross site domain location using an iframe not working anymore

Tags: javascript, iframe, xss

I have some legacy code that used to allow users to log into from other websites, but no longer works.

Here's how it worked. customerdomain.com embeds the following iframe:

```
<iframe src="https://webappdomain.com/c_login.php" style="width:380px;height:500px;border-radius:15px;margin:15px;" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Inside the iframe there is a submit button that takes a username/password and passes it to a .php page to authenticate as follows.  If the user authenticates at webappdomain.com, a cookie and php session is created and then a custom return code is sent back "200".

This is the jquery inside the iframe page "submit button":

```
jQuery.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "../includes/login_process.php",
   data:data,
   success: function(returnValue)
   {
        if(returnValue == 200)
        {
            parent.location.href="https://webappdomain.com/administrator/index.php";
            
        }else{
            //dispalay msg
        }
   }
});
```

Once the user authentication is good, we then tell the customerdomain.com page to go over to webappdomain.com as follows: `parent.location.href="https://webappdomain.com/administrator/index.php";`

We now get an error during the execution of the javascript in the console that says `"The operation is insecure."`

This used to work, but some time ago it stopped...I'm guessing it has to do with some cross site scripting changes to browsers...but I don't know how to solve this...been trying for some time to read up, but getting no where.  Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: One thing to look at is the server response headers from the iframe source domain. What you are looking for is the 'Content-Security-Policy' header, which, if set correctly, tells the browser that it's okay for this page to be embedded by the parent page. There is _much_ more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30280370/how-does-content-security-policy-csp-work

Comment: check following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49539306/firefox-service-worker-securityerror-domexception-the-operation-is-insecure/63831245#63831245

Comment: uotonyh I read that link, thanks...I tried putting this meta tag in the iframe but it gave me the same error:   <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src * data: 'unsafe-inline'; connect-src * 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src *;">