# "The operation is insecure." On navigator.credentials.create() on firefox using Mailcow

Tags: firefox, webauthn

I'm trying to register a fido2 device in Mailcow using Firefox 95.0.2.
When trying to do so, the Registration Status field announces:

```
The operation is insecure.
```

I've managed to track the error down to this line:

```js
return navigator.credentials.create(createCredentialArgs);
```

Where `createCredentialArgs` is:

```json
{"publicKey":{"rp":{"name":"WebAuthn Library","id":"subdomain.domain.tld:port"},"authenticatorSelection":{"userVerification":"preferred","requireResidentKey":true},"user":{"id":"=?BINARY?B?YWRtaW4=?=","name":"admin","displayName":"admin"},"pubKeyCredParams":[{"type":"public-key","alg":-7},{"type":"public-key","alg":-257}],"attestation":"direct","extensions":{"exts":true},"timeout":30000,"challenge":"=?BINARY?B?AJpcm\/8fHdnFDt60yDig2j14XLKtQmJfvslXLPIFj0g=?=","excludeCredentials":[]}}
```

The server uses a custom CA certificate present on the Mailcow installation, the client's host and Firefox.

Any ideas on why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing some more testing with Edge (and discovering the "thisisunsafe" trick), I've discovered that WebAuthn isn't a big fan of ports.
So, it didn't like: `"id":"subdomain.domain.tld:port"`.

Replacing `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` where `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` when initializing the `$WebAuthn` Variable fixed the issue.

Basically **navigator.credentials.create() doesn't accept ids with ports.**

Comment: Correct. The rpId is the effective domain. No IP address, no port, no scheme, no path. no TLD. It is explained here: https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-2/#relying-party-identifier